# Does B-C-E architecture pattern fits into Spring Boot multi-module application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, architecture

As a software developer I used to create and maintain JakartaEE backend applications.

It seems like for multi-module maven projects `boundary - control - entity` architecture fits really nice, especially when using *service* as a repository and *rest* for use-cases.

At the moment we need to transfer one of mid-size project into Spring (`war` packaged) and the question is:

**Will B-C-E architecture be a good match for modern MVC framework?**

Also, maybe a **module-as-use-case** would be a better approach for parent-child division?

Let me provide some example:

```
    service
        settlement
            boundary
            control
            entity
        user
            boundary
            control
            entity

    rest
        settlement
            boundary
            control
            entity
        user
            boundary
            control
            entity

    mail
        boundary
        control
        entity

    calculation
        boundary
        control
        entity
```

Project parent is a `pom` and has a `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on which aspect you're focusing on, but generally speaking, BCE is a natural way to structure classes which goes well with modularized architecture. One creates one BCE package structure per a micro-service, feature or module having ideally between 9 to 30 classes.